# bool and sizeof conditional template

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits

I'm testing a struct that I'm trying to use for template conditions, but I'm having some strange compiler errors. Here is my code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<typename T1, typename T2,
    bool SAME_SIZE = (sizeof(T1)==sizeof(T2))>
struct same_size
{
    typedef typename std::false_type value;
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct same_size<T1, T2, true>
{
    typedef typename std::true_type value;
};

int main()
{
    if(same_size<char,unsigned char>::value)
    {
        printf("yes");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

I'm compiling this in Visual Studio 2015. These are the compiler errors I get:

```
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\luis\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\stringtype\stringtype\main.cpp(18): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\users\luis\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\stringtype\stringtype\main.cpp(19): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
```

Can anyone shed some light as to what is going on here?

Comment: There's no need for those `typename`s in the `typedef`s. Another way to fix your error is to instantiate `value` - `if(same_size<char,unsigned char>::value{})`, but Sergey's answer is the right way to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having your `value` as a type, not a value. So you can't use it in `if` condition. The best thing you can do is to use inheritance and save on typing. Like so:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<typename T1, typename T2,
    bool SAME_SIZE = (sizeof(T1)==sizeof(T2))>
struct same_size : std::false_type
{
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct same_size<T1, T2, true> : std::true_type 
{
};

int main()
{
    if(same_size<char,unsigned char>::value)
    {
        printf("yes");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Another (better in my view) solution was suggested by @GManNickG:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct same_size : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(T1) == sizeof(T2)> {};
```

The benefits of above are, of course, less typing and less error prone: in the first solution, you could still write `same_size<int, int, false>::value` and get wrong results.

And the beauty of second solution is that it still is going produce types compatible with `true_type` and `false_type`, as latter are `typedefs` for corresponding `integral_constant`.

On a side note, seeing template metaprogramming and `printf` in the same code is like seeing space shuttle drawn by a pair of horses.

Comment: yeah I was just using printf because I was trying to test things. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think they always report the power of the space shuttle's engines in horsepower? It's so they'll know how many they'll need, just in case.

Comment: `template <typename T1, typename T2> struct same_size : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(T1) == sizeof(T2)> {};`, even simpler. (Or `std::bool_constant<>` in C++17.)

Comment: @GManNickG, I am used to Boost.MPL and prefer having something called true_type and false_type - makes overloading slightly less verbose. But sure thing, your solution is very valid.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yeah, NASA has it covered in all fields :)

Comment: @SergeyA: `true_type` and `false_type` are just `integral_constant<bool, true>` and `integral_constant<bool, false>` respectively, so I don't understand your concern.

Comment: Also, your solution allows me to do `same_size<int, int, false>` and get the wrong answer.

Comment: @GManNickG, less typing and more clear intention, this is the only reason. As for same_size<int, int, false> - this would be an abuse, to which a lot of metaprogromming techniques would be prone.

Comment: I'm confused, sorry; why is bring true_type and false_type into this relevant? The solution I suggested *is* shorter, and doesn't have the ability to be abused; why do the longer solution which is more easily abused?

Comment: @GManNickG, I am talking about the case when this type will be used for tag dispatch. `foo(std::true_type );` is cleaner to read than `foo( std::integral_constant<bool, true> );`

Comment: Those are the same thing. `std::true_type` *is* `std::integral_constant<bool, true>`

Comment: @GManNickG, ok, I see what you mean. Yes, this would be the same, shorter thing. Feel free to post as a better answer.

Comment: @SergeyA: Your answer is fine. :) You can just edit it if desired. I was just confused what you meant by needing to use true_type and false_type explicitly.

Comment: @GManNickG, I didn't quite see the fact that you can do it this way and still use `true_type` and `false_type` for tag dispatch. Thanks for bearing with me :) As for editing, wouldn't it be like taking credit for your code? :) I will edit with attribution.